# Searching for objects in nested NSSets

Tags: objective-c, ios, search, nsset

I am trying to get some objects from a complex structure of nested `NSSet`s, depicted below:

[image]

`obj1`, etc. is of type `MyObject`.

I used a predicate but it did not return anything:

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass:%@",[MYObject class]];
```

I think `NSPredicate` looks for the first layer of objects in NSSet.[Highlighted above].

To overcome this issue I traverse through all the sets and get the `MyObject` instances. Is there any better approach than this? It's too time consuming to get values for `obj1`,`obj2`,`obj3`,`obj4`.

Comment: You have to get them one by one

Comment: Eventually thats what I did, as I was not able to find better solution for it.

Comment: You should probably consider using some other data structure rather than sets if they're slow.

Comment: @Jessedc Thanks, can you help me implementing a Tree in Objective C?